# Creating a Singly Linked List with Data from a Filestream

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm currently attempting to create a program that will create a linked list containing the following in each node:

1. pointer to the next node (obviously needed)
2. a string read in from a line of text from the file stream
3. a count of how many times the string was encountered in the filestream

I have the following code but, I'm running into a couple issues that I'm clearly  failing to grasp:

1. How to search the list and then create a node if a corresponding node wasn't found in the list already?
2. In general, how to create the head node and then start linking subsequent nodes to it?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've spent many hours googling and watching youtube videos to no avail.

```
typedef struct List
    {
       struct List *next;
       char *str;
       int count;
    } List;
```

The above is from a provided header file. Below is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "C2A6E4_List-Driver.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE 255  /*Define the size of the array*/

List *CreateLinkedList(FILE *fp)
{
   List *head, *ptr, *p;
   head = NULL;
   char tempBuffer[ARRAY_SIZE];

   while (fgets(tempBuffer, ARRAY_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
   {
      char *strToken = strtok(tempBuffer, " ");

      while (strToken != NULL)
      {
         for (p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
            ;
         if (strcmp(p->str, strToken) == 0)
         {
            p->count++;
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            if ((ptr = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List))) == NULL)
            {
               fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory!");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if ((ptr->str = (char *)malloc(strlen(strToken) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(char))) == NULL)
            {
               fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory!");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            memcpy(&ptr->str, &strToken, sizeof(strToken));
            ptr->count = 1;

            if (head != NULL)
            {
               p = head;
               p->next = ptr;
            }
            else
               head = ptr;
         }
         strToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
   }
   return head;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use hash instead?

Comment: funny you mention that because that's unfortunately next week's lesson so I'm just working with what I was semi taught.

Comment: you've got a semicolon after your `for` loop

Comment: From what I've seen/read in my book that's intentional as it will just move to the end of the linked list.

Comment: `memcpy(&ptr->str, &strToken, sizeof(strToken));` is suspicious.   Perhasp `strcpy(ptr->str, strToken);`?

Comment: Chux, it was recommended to use memcpy vs strcpy. It was noted to be used for efficiency purposes.

Comment: A design tip.Don't keep data inside a Node.Create a struct to hold your data , and create a Node with one pointer to the next node and one pointer to your struct.You keep things clear this way and if 3 months later you would like to update your data , then you will have only to fix your struct.